# Use features based on tf idf score for text classification using naive bayes (sklearn)

Tags: scikit-learn, tf-idf, text-classification, feature-selection, naivebayes

I am learning to implement text classification (into two classes)  using tfidf and naive bayes by referring to [this blog](https://appliedmachinelearning.wordpress.com/2017/02/12/sentiment-analysis-using-tf-idf-weighting-pythonscikit-learn/) and [sklearn tfidf](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html)

below is the code snippet:

```
kf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)
totalNB = 0
totalMatNB = np.zeros((2,2));

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(documents, labels):
    X_train = [documents[i] for i in train_index]
    X_test = [documents[i] for i in test_index]
    y_train, y_test = labels[train_index], labels[test_index]
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=2, max_df= 0.2, use_idf= True, stop_words=stop_words)
    train_corpus_tf_idf = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)
    test_corpus_tf_idf = vectorizer.transform(X_test)
    model2 = MultinomialNB()
    model2.fit(train_corpus_tf_idf, y_train)
    result2 = model2.predict(test_corpus_tf_idf)
    totalMatNB = totalMatNB + confusion_matrix(y_test, result2)
    totalNB = totalNB + sum(y_test == result2)
```

The above code is working as expected.

I have read the documents, but I am still confuse about **min_df** and **max_df**.

How to **use the features for the classification based on the tf-idf score**, i.e. filter the features based on tf-idf score 
eg.

1. use the features whose tf-idf score is greater than x [ score(features) >x]
2. use the features whose tf-idf score between x and y [ y> score(features)>x ] or [ y>= score(features)>=x ]

Answer (score 1):

When training the vectorizer, setting specific values for `min_df` and `max_df` is supposed to help you tweak the eventual tf-idf representation to best suit your needs by limiting the vocabulary. It also helps with reducing the dimension of the vector representation which is usually a good thing since they tend to be huge.

- Setting a high `min_df` value will remove relatively infrequent terms from the representation. If your eventual model is not supposed to care too much about very unique terms this would be a good thing.
- Setting a low `max_df` will remove relatively frequent terms from the representation. If your eventual model doesn't care about words that are used in many contexts (e.g. "the", "or", "and") then this would be a good thing. Note that "low" here can mean either a nonzero integer > 1 or a float < 1 close to 0.

Important note: your suggestion of filtering features after-the-fact based on their tf-idf weight is a totally different thing. Setting `min_df` and `max_df` when fitting the vectorizer will limit the eventual vocabulary based on document frequency across the entire training sample. Whereas the eventual tf-idf weight in a given vector is a document-specific value (since it's also impacted by the term frequency in that specific document).

Hope this helps!